# Bulk email from Powershell data table

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a script that connects to SQL, pulls a dataset and formats it. I then need to send emails to the managers for each team along with an Html table and I cant think of the best way to proceed with the second half.

Data is formatted like so: `Team | Item | Manager email`

Every Item is unique, so a few can appear beside the same team and the same email.
Would something like the following be workable:
`For each  $_.ManagerEmail in $dataset ( build html output containing each unique item)`

They should obviously only receive one email rather than one for each item.
Any thoughts or pointers please?

EDIT:
Thanks for your input guys. I tried to implement Mathias' suggestion but the script is finishing with no output or errors now. I know the SQL part works fine so the issue is here.

```
foreach($ManagerSet in $Dataset.Rows |Group-Object "Manager Email")
{ 
$Items = $ManagerSet.Group |Select-Object Item 
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application 
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0) 
$Mail.To = $ManagerSet.ManEmails 
$Mail.Subject = "Test" $Mail.Body = 'Testing. Failures include' + $managerset.itemname + $managerset.Info1 $Mail.Send() 
}
```

Any pointers on what I've missed?

Comment: you would probably need to go through all the items and sort them, if you want to send one email for several items, I don't see any other way to achieve that

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest grouping the rows in the data table by the "Manager Email" column, then send one email per group:

```
foreach($ManagerSet in $Datatable.Rows |Group-Object "Manager Email")
{
    $Items = $ManagerSet.Group |Select-Object Item
    # Compose email containing $Items in here. 
    # You can refer to the email address via $ManagerSet.Name
}
```

This way you can send a single email per team/manager containing all relevant items

Answer (score 0):

We should user Invoke-SQlCmd to output SQL data as Datatable for this to work. But even after that no values are returned for Items