# PowerShell: How to Send one Mail using for loop with whole datasets values

Tags: powershell, email, powershell-3.0

I've below data from the SQL query and trying to send one mail for each data set array.

Query Results:

```
ID  |  email      | Value <br />
+++++++++++++++ <br/>
1   | abc@mail  | 10 <br />
1   | abc@mail  | 12 <br />
1   | abc@mail  | 13 <br />
2   | def@mail  | 11 <br />
2   | def@mail  | 10 <br />
2   | def@mail  | 15    <br />
```

I'm using for loop to read through the data

After reading the values I'm trying to find how I can send one mail to each user abc@mail and def@mail.com with all three entries. Means abc@mail should get one mail only with the below details in the subject and def@mail should also get one mail with the other three values

```
ID  | email    |  Value <br />

1    |abc@mail  | 10 <br />
1    |abc@mail  | 12 <br />
1    |abc@mail  | 13 <br />
```

For loop code to send mail currently which is now sending different mail for each row.

```
    foreach ($dataset in $QueryRes)
    {  
         $id = $dataset.ID
         $mail =$dataset.mail
         $value = $dataset.Value
         $Subject = "Testing"
         $BodyText = "<font style='font-family:Calibri' size='2'><b>Hi  
         $mail </b> <br><br>" +
         "some Text"+
         $dataset.ItemArray" + <br><br>"
         Send-MailMessage To "$mail" From "xyz@mail" -subject $subject - 
         BOdy $BodyText -smptpServer "Value"
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Interesting question but may you please provide your actual code?

Comment: Updated the part of code I'm using to send mail currently which is now sending each mail for row in the dataset.

Comment: I cant see any change

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 1):

Checking what you have here in loop I would do it like this (note that I am not a powershell developer, so I propose a rough idea)

Create a hash table and assign multiple values to a single email in loop (you do not use id, I omit that), see code:

```
$myHashTable = @{} # creates hash table
if ($myHashTable.ContainsKey($dataset.mail)) {
  $myHashTable[$dataset.mail] += $dataset.Value
} else {
  $myHashTable[$dataset.mail] = @()
  $myHashTable[$dataset.mail] += $dataset.Value
}
```

When the hash table is created, loop over it and send mail to each single mail with all the data in the values, should look something like this:

```
$myHashTable.Keys | % { "key = $_ , value = " + $myHashTable.Item($_) ---do the rest you need here---}
```

This is just an idea, there might be smarter way to do it. I do not say the code works, I have just checked out how powershell hash tables are created and put something together, so you might need to edit this.

EDIT:
I have found a way to group on emails [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579445/bulk-email-from-powershell-data-table):

```
foreach($EmailSet in $QueryRes.Rows |Group-Object "mail")
{
    $Items = $EmailSet.Group |Select-Object Item
    # Compose email containing $Items in here. 
    # You can refer to the email address via $ManagerSet.Name
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Idea.
Can I add more column values? Means I have one more column-like start and end time in the dataset which I didn't specify here?

Comment: you might check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50359533/create-hashtable-where-key-has-multiple-array-values)

Comment: I can loop through these custom objects just like normal datasets? like
Foreach ( $dataset in $DataSetList) ? here the dataset list contains custom objects bind together.

Comment: I have provided how can you loop over it in my answer

Comment: $myHashTable.Keys | % { "key = $_ , value = " + $myHashTable.Item($_)
You mean this one?

Comment: I have found possibly better solution, see edit (and yes, that one :))

Comment: I tried below but it's not entering into for loop
foreach ($dataset in $QueryRes.Rows |Group-Object "mail")

here the mail coming from $QueryRes.Rows.I'm wondering do I need to create to create PSCustomObject First and then loop throug them?

Comment: well I have expected your data $QueryRes is of type Data Table, I have no skills with powershell so you will have to figure that out, I am sorry